# Node.js require once or multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, requirejs

I have this 2 files:

- APP.js:

```js
const Request = require('request');
const YVideo = require('./classes/YVideo');
const yvideo = new YTVideo();
```

- YVideo.js:

```js
class YVideo {
  constructor(uuid){
    this.uuid = uuid;
    this.url = 'https://example.com/get_video_info?uuid=';
    Request.get(this.url+this.uuid, function(err, resp, body){
      this.data = body.split('&');
    });
    console.log(this.data);
  }
}
exports = module.exports = YTVideo;
```

The code runs until "**Request.get(...)**". Console shows this error:
"**ReferenceError: Request is not defined**".

Now, I'm new with Node.js, so what I ask is: Should I require the same module each time for all .js where I use it or there's a way to require it once for entire app?

Comment: Add it in every file that you use it in, they are singletons and only actually get loaded once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question: Should I require the same module each time for all .js where I use it
>   or there's a way to require it once for entire app?

`require` locally loads each module, so you will have to use `require` in every `.js` file you need the module.

From https://www.w3resource.com/node.js/nodejs-global-object.php

> The require() function is a built-in function, and used to include
>   other modules that exist in separate files, a string specifying the
>   module to load. It accepts a single argument. It is not global but
>   rather local to each module.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be required in all the files where you need it. So add it in YVideo file where it is needed.

```
const Request = require('request');
class YVideo {
  constructor(uuid){
    this.uuid = uuid;
    this.url = 'https://example.com/get_video_info?uuid=';
    Request.get(this.url+this.uuid, function(err, resp, body){
      this.data = body.split('&');
    });
    console.log(this.data);
  }
}
exports = module.exports = YTVideo;
```